# Refused Connection from android to sqlserver

Tags: java, android, sql-server, jdbc, tcp

This is my code to connect to SqlServer from Android Application

```
private Connection CONN(String _DB, String _server)
{
   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
   String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://AhmedPc:1433; Instance=SQL2008;" +
                          "databaseName=admin1;integratedSecurity=true;";
   Connection con = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   try 
   {
     Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
     con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
     String SQL = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Person.Contact";
     stmt = con.createStatement();
     rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
     while (rs.next()) 
     {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(4) + " " + rs.getString(6));
     }
   }

   catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   finally {
       if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
       if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
       if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
   }
   return con;
}
```

I get this Error

When I use the Ip address 42.xx.xx.xx i  get this::::

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host  has failed. java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to / (port 1433): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

When i use the 127.0.0.1  i get this:::::

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host  has failed. java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to / (port 1433): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Comment: Maybe a firewall or SQL SERVER security feature

Comment: user2310289 try to ping the IP address in ur cmd prompt.

Comment: i print 127.0.0.1 and i am getting replay

Comment: and i use the telnet for Ip address with the port 1433 and it's not used by any program